# How to verify the URL is valid

Tags: swift3

How do I verify the Url is valid?

Say I have this URL:

> http://www.example.com:80/dir/?query=test

**Problem:**

I need to verify the Url as follows:

1. Make sure URL is valid Check Scheme: which scheme is used: `HTTP` or `HTTPS`
2. Remove port no if it is in the `URL`
3. Return an absolute URL string get the host, get the path as below

> url = http://host/absolutePath

Example:

> https://www.example.com/dir/?query=test

I try this:

```
var strURL = NSURL(string:"http://www.example.com:80/dir/?query=test")

if(strURL?scheme == "http" && strURL?scheme == "https"){

// remove the Port No   
} else {

}
```

How to remove the port No and reconstruct the URL as a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with `URLComponents`

```
func validate(url : String) -> String? {
    guard var components = URLComponents(string: url),
        (components.scheme == "http" || components.scheme == "https") else { return nil }
    components.port = nil
    return components.string
}

let strURL = "http://www.example.com:80/dir/?query=test"
let url = validate(url: strURL) // "http://www.example.com/dir/?query=test"
```

Answer (score 0):

check this if this helps

```
func testUrl(string: String) -> String? {
        var stringUrl: String?
        if let url = URL(string: string){
            if url.scheme == "http" || url.scheme == "https"{
                stringUrl = url.absoluteString
                if let port = url.port{
                   stringUrl =  stringUrl?.replacingOccurrences(of: ":\(port)", with: "")
                }
            }
        }
        return stringUrl
    }
```